# How can I show images from a Google Drive folder?

Tags: php, laravel, google-drive-api

I am building a testing website. In login confirmation, I have to show the examinee their pictures, which is already saved in Google Drive Folder.

```
$optParams = array(
            'pageSize' => 1,
            'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(contentHints/thumbnail,fileExtension,id,name,size)',
            'q' =>"mimeType contains 'image/' AND name contains '".$imageId."' AND '".$folderIdId."' in parents"
          );
          $results = $googleDriveService->files->listFiles($optParams);
          
        if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
            print "No files found.\n";
        } else {
            print "Files:\n";
            foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
                printf("%s (%s)\n", $file->getName(), $file->getId());
            }
        }
```

This is what I used to get the file ID. Now in order to preview the image to the page, do I have to download the image (then delete it later) in order to show it, or is there another way to do it without downloading?

Comment: Check this article https://support.awesome-table.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002196665-Display-images-from-Google-Drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*While Drive is not designed to be a hosting platform, you use the preview link as a workaround.*

#### More Information:

I really should reiterate here: Drive is not designed to be an image hosting platform. It is a file sharing and cloud storage solution primarily, but does provide methods of viewing images via preview, view and embed links.

You can use the following link, replacing `[ID]` with your image ID to embed or preview an image in a page:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=[ID]
```

**NB:** While this works, the image will load slowly as image hosting is not the M.O. of Drive.
There is also an iframe option provided in the form of an embed:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/[ID]/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

This iframe embed is obtainable from the Drive UI:

After double-clicking your image at [drive.google.com](https://drive.google.com), and following the `⋮ > Open in new window` menu item, in the newly opened tab follow the `⋮ > Embed item...` menu option and the iframe code will open in a modal.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. You need to follow the GOOGLE DRIVE API docs. This code takes a file and uploads it to google drive. Records the URL and the "name" in a database for use in displaying the images later. I installed multer in express.js to help with multiple image uploads.

```
app.post('/api/uploadmultiple', uploader.any("files", 12),
    async (req, res, next) => {
    const scopes = [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    ];
    const stream = require('stream');
    const { google } = require('googleapis');
    const credentials = require('./google-credentials.json');
    let fileObject = req.files[0];
    let bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
    bufferStream.end(fileObject.buffer);

    const auth = new google.auth.JWT(
      credentials.client_email, null,
      credentials.private_key, scopes
    );

    const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });
    const fileName = req.files[0].originalname;
    const fileType = req.files[0].mimetype;

    var fileMetadata = {
      name: fileName, // file name that will be saved in google drive
    };

    var media = {
      mimeType: fileType,
      body: req.files[0].buffer, // Reading the file from our server
    };
    var petname = req.body.petname;
 
    // Uploading Single image to drive

    drive.files.create(
      {
        media: {
          mimeType: fileType,
          body: bufferStream
        },
        resource: {
          name: fileName,
          // if you want to store the file in the root, remove this parents
          parents: ['GET THIS ID FROM GOOGLE DRIVE']
        },
        fields: 'id',
      }).then(function (resp) {
        if (resp.data) {
          res.status(200).end("File uploaded");
          var fileLocation = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=" + resp.data.id;
          console.log("Upload Success", fileLocation);
          db.addPet(petname, fileLocation);
          db.addImage(petname, fileName, fileLocation);
        }
        console.log(resp.data.id,'resp');
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500);
      })});
```