# How to get raw image from a public url?

Tags: node.js, image, google-drive-api

I was trying to host an image with Google Drive API in node.

```
await drive.files.create({
  requestBody: {
    role: "render",
    type: "anyone",
  },
});

const response = await drive.files.get({
  fileId: "...",
  fields: "webViewLink, webContentLink",
});

console.log(response.data);
```

I was getting a public link to the image which I can open inside Google Drive or download to be able to view it manually.

```
{
  webContentLink: 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1dffGf_4R5W75xKGhx7n-nXsZPFA7NE1a&export=download',
  webViewLink: 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dffGf_4R5W75xKGhx7n-nXsZPFA7NE1a/view?usp=drivesdk' 
}
```

But this is not what I want.

I want the public images to be in raw format (jpg, png, etc.) and should be able to be viewed normally like a website in the browser.

I hope I've explained it enough, any help is really appreciated :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current issue from `But this is not what I want. I want the public images to be in raw format (jpg, png, etc.) and should be able to be viewed normally like a website in the browser.`. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: You can't get this. However, as a workaround, if you want to embed the image into a webpage, you can use the preview link https://stackoverflow.com/a/62571215/11551468

Comment: Google drive is a file storage system not a web hosting site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found that instead of this...

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-x3h_1lYrBat7K43LaiTlS9FqQttbbFW/view?usp=sharing
```

I could pass pass thumbnail followed by the `file id` like this...

```
https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1-x3h_1lYrBat7K43LaiTlS9FqQttbbFW
```

This works well and could be embedded into the `src` attribute of the `img` tag... ([source](https://dev.to/imamcu07/embed-or-display-image-to-html-page-from-google-drive-3ign)).